# Eclipse: Error initializing endpoint java.net.BindException: Permission denied:443

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, permissions, bind

I'm on Mac OS X Lion and am currently using eclipse to deploy a project with the help of JBoss.

I get the following error:

> Error initializing endpoint java.net.BindException: Permission
>   denied:443

I understand this is a permissions issue, how do I allow eclipse to bind to port 443 in Mac OS X?

Answer (score 3):

On *-nix platforms, you generally can't bind to privileged ports (< 1024) if you aren't the root user.

If you are working in a development environment, you could configure JBoss to use a different port for SSL (8081, for instance) and point your testers/browser there.

If you absolutely need to use port 443 and can't run as root (which isn't recommended anyhow), you can:

- configure JBoss to use a different port
- configure a proxy
  ([Polipo](https://www.irif.fr/%7Ejch/software/polipo/), for
  instance) to re-direct port 443

If you don't want separate proxy software, you could also configure iptables. See [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/tomcat/HowTo).

Comment: would it be possible to give my user account permission to bind to 443?